# Permutations with repeated objects

Tags: permutations

> In school $100$ kids are making necklaces from $11$ beads. Every kid gets this same set of beads: red , green, blue. Choose the sets which allow every kid to make different necklace:
>
> **a)** 7-red, 2-green, 2-green
>
> **b)** 7-red, 3-green, 1-blue
>
> **c)** 6-red, 4-green, 1-blue
>
> **d)** 8-red, 2-green, 1-blue
>
> **e)** 3-red, 1-green, 7-blue

I was trying to do this with a lot of ways for example:

**a)** $$ \frac {11!}{7!\cdot 2!\cdot 2!} = 1980  $$ which should give the all possible ways of making different necakles, but doing this that way gives for all sets numbers higher than $100$ so all answers would be true, but in my book the good answers are only **a)** and **c)**.

I don't know there is a mistake in a book or my way of doing this is wrong.

I will be very thankful for every help.

Comment: necakle -> necklace

Comment: I am so sorry for mistakes. English is not my native language

Comment: The necklace is a circle - perhaps you need to divide all your answers by 11 to compensate for the fact that the answers you got assumed that there was a beginning and an end to each string of beads.

Comment: @Serek nor mine. Don't be worried by my remark, it was only intended to have the most readable text.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The cycle index  $Z(C_{11})$ of the cyclic group  acting on the eleven
slots is very simple because $11$ is prime and we obtain

$$Z(C_{11}) = \frac{1}{11} (a_1^{11} + 10 a_{11}).$$

Substitution by PET (Polya Enumeration Theorem)  now yields

$$\frac{1}{11} ((R+G+B)^{11} + 10 (R^{11}+G^{11}+B^{11})).$$

None of the proposed  combinations are monochromatic containing eleven
beads of the same color, hence only the first term contributes.

We have for

**a.** $$\frac{1}{11} {11\choose 7,2,2} = 180$$

**b.** $$\frac{1}{11} {11\choose 7,3,1} = 120$$

**c.** $$\frac{1}{11} {11\choose 6,4,1} = 210$$

**d.** $$\frac{1}{11} {11\choose 8,2,1} = 45$$

**e.** $$\frac{1}{11} {11\choose 3,1,7} = 120$$.

Hence all  choices except  **d** allow every  kid to make  a different
necklace. What we  see here is that all  orbits except monochrome ones
are the same size, containing $11$ configurations.